# Unwrap div wrapper and then wrap in unordered list and wrap children in list items

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I have the following markup:

```
 <div class="idx-results idx-grid grid_size_2 clearfix">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col grid_6_of_12 featlist">a</div>
    <div class="col grid_6_of_12 featlist">b</div>
 </div>
```

I would like to acheive the following output:

```
 <div class="idx-results idx-grid grid_size_2 clearfix">
  <ul class="bxslider">
    <li class="col grid_6_of_12 featlist">a</li>
    <li class="col grid_6_of_12 featlist">b</li>
 </ul>
```

This I thought would be the solution but no dice!

```
$(".idx-results .row").unwrap().wrap('<ul/>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('.idx-results > .row').wrapInner('<ul />').contents().unwrap();
$('.idx-results .col').wrapInner('<li />').contents().unwrap()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2azkT/)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply `unwrap()` the `contents()` and re-`wrap()` it with a new element.

But if you want to retain all the `attributes` of the old element, then this should be the solution:

```
var $old = $('.row'),
    $new = $('<ul/>');
//loop through all the attributes of the $old element
//then set it on our new element - $new
$.each($old[0].attributes, function (i, attr) {
    $new.attr(attr.name, attr.value);
});
//copy the $old element html contents
$new.html($old.html());
//and swap with the $new element
$old.replaceWith($new);
```

See this [**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SLykt/2/).